# Backbone collection: Retrieve distinct values of a collection

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have backbone collection of models and would like to retrieve the distinct values of a certain property

If I have loaded data like the following into my collection:

```
[{brand:'audi',id:'1234'},
{brand:'audi',id:'3456'},
{brand:'bmw',id:'3456'}]
```

I would now want to get the distinct brands from the collection. The result should be:

```
['audi','bmw']
```

Looking at the Backbone and Underscore API I don't see anything obvious to achieve this. 
My current approach would be to use a library like [jslinq](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/)

Am I missing anything obvious or does somebody have a better suggestion than jslinq?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) and then use [uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) (example: http://jsfiddle.net/sCVyN/5/)

pluck

> A convenient version of what is perhaps the most common use-case for
>   map: extracting a list of property values.

uniq

> Produces a duplicate-free version of the array, using `===` to test
>   object equality. If you know in advance that the array is sorted,
>   passing true for isSorted will run a much faster algorithm. If you
>   want to compute unique items based on a transformation, pass an
>   iterator function.

Comment: Nice! I hadn't looked at pluck yet!

Comment: I got this error running the jsFiddle. "Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/documentcloud/underscore/master/underscore.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled." I forked it at http://jsfiddle.net/manuelhe/PEfew/1/ using underscore from cdnjs