# Backbone collection: Retrieve distinct values of a collection and sum the distinct values

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599123/backbone-collection-retrieve-distinct-values-of-a-collection)

given this "sample collection data":

```
[{brand:'audi', amount: '100.16', id:'1234'},
{brand:'audi', amount: '67.84', id:'3456'},
{brand:'bmw', amount: '80.70', id:'3456'}]
```

how can i add the amount of the distinct brands from the collection?

and get this data:

```
[{brand:'audi', amount: '168.00'},
{brand:'bmw', amount: '80.70'}]
```

thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty standard [`reduce`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and that's just straight JavaScript:

```
var o = data.reduce(function(m, e) {
    // There are lots of ways to do this depending on what sorts
    // of things are going to be values in `m`, we're expecting
    // the values to be non-zero numbers so a simple `!` is fine.
    if(!m[e.brand])
        m[e.brand] = 0;
    m[e.brand] += parseFloat(e.amount);
    return m;
}, { });
```

If you're worried about stone age browsers then use `_(data).reduce` or a simple loop:

```
var o = { }, i;
for(i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    if(!o[data[i].brand])
        o[data[i].brand] = 0;
    o[data[i].brand] += parseFloat(data[i].amount]);
}
```

You should be pretty safe with floating point values as long as they're all small and close together like those are.

Comment: thanks! nice idea! i works only if you dont use the Backbone Collection. =)

Comment: If `data` is actually a collection rather than an array then you could use `data.reduce(...)`.

Comment: but im getting this error `Object {undefined: NaN} ` kindly check the log of this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jrsalunga/3mk9B/

Comment: That's because a collection's `reduce` iterates over models, not objects: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Sb8rR/

Answer (score 1):

This solution firsts groups the cars by brand and then uses good old reduce to sum the amounts:

```
var carsByBrand = _.groupBy(cars, 'brand');

var sumAmount = function(total, car){ 
    return total + parseFloat(car.amount); 
}

var sums = _.map( carsByBrand, function(cars, brand){
    return {
        brand: brand,
        amount: _.reduce(cars, sumAmount, 0)
    };
});
```